# In org-mode, how to always display inline images at Emac's startup?

Tags: org-mode, images

On Emacs (Mac) I have saved a desktop which opens two .org files (one of this has an image - jpg) and whenever I open up Emacs, I have to always type `y` to:

`display /route/to/image/Logo.jpg? (y or n)`

How can I make `y` the default? *Haven't found a way to do it, so here I am.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you already tried?:   `(setq org-startup-with-inline-images t)`  This can also be done on a per file basis:  http://orgmode.org/manual/In_002dbuffer-settings.html

Comment: You also might want to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129338/inline-images-in-org-mode) out.

Comment: @lawlist 
Thank you! I'm new on this site, don't know how to set you as the correct answer.

Comment: You can't mark it as correct unless @lawlist reposts it as an answer instead of a comment..  Then you can upvote it and check the "accepted" button to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The variable `org-startup-with-inline-images` can be set globally with the following in the `.emacs` or `init.el` file [the default value is `nil`] -- *Non-nil means show inline images when loading a new Org file.*:

```lisp
(setq org-startup-with-inline-images t)
```

**or**, it can be set locally as described in the doc-string:  *This can also be configured on a per-file basis by adding one of the following lines anywhere in the buffer:*

```
#+STARTUP: inlineimages
#+STARTUP: noinlineimages
```

Here is a link to the manual on this subject:  http://orgmode.org/manual/In_002dbuffer-settings.html