# Package for live inline rendering for markdown/org mode text with css styling?

Tags: spacemacs, package, markdown

Currently, I use [Typora](https://typora.io/) (a markdown editor) for all my personal notes and documentation. After seeing the capabilities of emacs in a colleague's spacemacs setup, I am very interested in switching from writing personal documentation in markdown to org-mode. But are there are emacs packages/plugins that can match the following two Typora features?

1. Is there an emacs plugin for live, inline rendering of org-mode or markdown text with css themes? By "inline" rendering, I mean markup is rendered in the same window that you type in (see gif below)
   [image: a gif demonstrating inline rendering of markdown in Typora]
2. Is there a way to render images inline in org-mode documentation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to question 2 is yes! If you have an image `cat.png` in the same folder as you org file, you can insert it using simply `[[./cat.png]]` and toggle inline display with `C-c C-x C-v`. Here's a [link](https://orgmode.org/manual/Images.html) to the relevant org documentation.

If you want inline images to be displayed by default, as suggested in [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/14776/27286) you can add the following line to your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html):

```el
(setq org-startup-with-inline-images t)
```

Question 1 is not as simple. Strictly speaking, I don't think you can use CSS to control the display of text in an Emacs buffer. However, there are extensive visual customisation options for Emacs in general and for `org-mode` in particular which allow us to get an aesthetic similar to that of Typora. For an example of what is possible, see the screenshot below by Abhinav Tushar, described in detail [here](https://lepisma.xyz/2017/10/28/ricing-org-mode/index.html), or the following [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/unixporn/comments/73vwpa/stumpwm_light_colors_with_purple_accent/).

[image: org-mode demo by Abhinav Tushar]

Below I will try to provide an `org-mode` customisation that makes it visually similar to the Typora example. First, here's how the example text looks in a vanilla Emacs 27 setup (no customisations) on Ubuntu 20.04.

[image: org-mode in vanilla Emacs 27]

As you can see, we have hyperlinks by default as well as boldface and italic text. However, emphasis markers (`*, /`) are still displayed, there is no word wrap, a fixed-width font is used throughout and the title is the same size as the main text.

---

**Basic customisation: no emphasis markers, word wrap and clean UI**

We start with simple settings that don't require any additional packages: we hide emphasis markers such as `*` or `/`, enable word wrapping by default in `org-mode` and hide the toolbar, menu bar and scroll bar.

```el
;; hide emphasis markers
(setq org-hide-emphasis-markers t)

;; word wrap
(with-eval-after-load 'org       
  (add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'visual-line-mode))

;; disable toolbar, menu bar and scroll bar
(tool-bar-mode -1)
(menu-bar-mode -1)
(toggle-scroll-bar -1)
```

Emacs now looks as follows:

[image: org with first customisations]

---

**Changing fonts, removing asterisks, increasing line spacing and changing list markers**

The most obvious difference between our example and Typora is now the font. The font in the Typora example looks like a clone of the classic [Palatino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatino). Due to Palatino's popularity, some version of this font is available in most systems. However, to make this answer as general as possible, we will use the [TeX Gyre Pagella](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/pagella) font, a Palatino clone developed primarily with LaTeX in mind and which therefore has good math support. It's available in PS Type 1 and OTF formats and free to download and use.

After we install Pagella on our system, we can configure `org-mode` to use it for text while using a monospaced font for code, tables, etc. (I tend to use [Adobe's Source Code Pro](http://adobe-fonts.github.io/source-code-pro/), which is also free and [available on GitHub](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro)). We could do this by changing `org-mode`'s settings ourselves but it's easier to have the [`mixed-pitch`](https://gitlab.com/jabranham/mixed-pitch) package handle this for us.

When using external packages, it's convenient to set [MELPA](https://melpa.org/) as the default repository and have [`use-package`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) take care of the package configuration, so we start by adding the following lines to the start of our init file:

```el
;; set up MELPA package repo
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)

;; use-package to simplify package loading
(unless (package-installed-p `use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install `use-package))
(eval-when-compile
  (require 'use-package))
```

We can now add the relevant code for changing fonts:

```el
;; set fixed-width font
(set-face-font 'default "Source Code Pro-12")

;; set variable-width font
(set-face-font 'variable-pitch "TeX Gyre Pagella-13")

;; set org-mode to use variable width fonts smartly
(use-package mixed-pitch
  :ensure t
  :hook (text-mode . mixed-pitch-mode))
```

To improve the aesthetics further, we can make the header font larger and bold, hide the asterisk using the [`org-bullets`](https://github.com/sabof/org-bullets) package, use black squares (Unicode character [U+25AA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters)) instead of hyphens as list markers (following [Diego Zamboni](https://zzamboni.org/post/beautifying-org-mode-in-emacs/)) and [increase the line spacing](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_toggle_line_spacing.html):

```el
;; increase header font size and weight
(custom-set-faces
  '(org-level-1 ((t (:height 1.3 :weight bold))))
  '(org-level-2 ((t (:height 1.2 :weight bold))))
  '(org-level-3 ((t (:height 1.1 :weight bold)))))

;; hide asterisks in headers
(use-package org-bullets
  :ensure t
  :config
  (add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (org-bullets-mode 1)))
  (setq org-bullets-bullet-list '("\u200b")))

;; change list markers from hyphens to squares
(font-lock-add-keywords 'org-mode
                        '(("^ *\\([-]\\) "
                           (0 (prog1 () (compose-region (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1) "▪"))))))

;; increase line spacing
(setq-default line-spacing 0.5)
```

This gives us the following appearance:

[image: org with new font]

---

**Finishing touches: emulating Typora's Focus Mode**

Typora provides [two interesting modes](https://support.typora.io/Focus-and-Typewriter-Mode/) for displaying text which can be used either jointly or separately: with Focus Mode, paragraphs other than the current one (where the cursor is) are displayed in a dim grey colour; and with Typewriter Mode, the cursor is always centred vertically on the page.

We can emulate the behaviour of Typora's Focus Mode with the [`focus`](https://github.com/larstvei/Focus) package. After installing and loading the package, we can turn on `focus-mode` with `M-x focus-mode`. For Typewriter Mode, things are more complicated: the [`centered-cursor-mode`](https://github.com/emacsmirror/centered-cursor-mode) package implements this behaviour but is still under development and is not available on the MELPA repository. However, you can [modify Emacs settings](https://two-wrongs.com/centered-cursor-mode-in-vanilla-emacs) to achieve a similar functionality if you wish.

Going beyond these two modes, I would also recommend the lovely [`olivetti`](https://github.com/rnkn/olivetti) package: it increases the text's side margins, making it easier and more pleasant to read. We add the following lines to our init file:

```el
;; focus mode
(use-package focus
  :ensure t)

;; olivetti for wider margins
(use-package olivetti
  :ensure t)
```

Finally, we can set a new theme such as [`doom-tomorrow-day`](https://github.com/hlissner/emacs-doom-themes) (this has the advantage of changing the colour of the text dimmed by `focus` to grey rather than dark red as in the default theme) and [remove the modeline](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HideModeLine):

```el
;; hide modeline
(setq-default mode-line-format nil) 

;; change theme
(use-package doom-themes
  :ensure t
  :config
  ;; Global settings (defaults)
  (setq doom-themes-enable-bold t    ; if nil, bold is universally disabled
        doom-themes-enable-italic t)  ; if nil, italics is universally disabled
  (load-theme 'doom-tomorrow-day t)  ; theme
  (doom-themes-org-config))  ; corrects (and improves) org-mode's native fontification
```

Our Emacs now looks like this:

[image: final Emacs look]

And that's it! As you can see, Emacs can do [most of what you might want out of a text editor and more](https://xkcd.com/378/). ;)

Comment: This is one of the best answers that I've ever gotten on SE. Thanks so much! Is there a resource that lists all the available options that can be set in the emacs init config file if I want to further experiment and extend what you've shown here?

Comment: Thank you very much, glad I could help! For Emacs' own customisation options (no packages) a good place to start might be the Customize menu accessible through `M-x customize`. For finding useful packages, you could take a look at the [Awesome Emacs](https://github.com/emacs-tw/awesome-emacs) list. Finally, you could try an Emacs distribution such as [Doom](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs) (very popular and lighter than Spacemacs) for a polished and modern experience. Even if you later build your own config, it will give you an idea of which packages you find most useful. Good luck! ;)

Comment: As a Vim user, this answer sold me to Emacs.