# How to always display inline images by default? Existing solutions don't seem to take effect

Tags: org-mode, inline-image

I'm trying to always display inline images in my org mode files.

I have images inserted as `[[my-image.png]]`.

What I have already tried:

1. Set startup variable (see [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14758/in-org-mode-how-to-always-display-inline-images-at-emacs-startup):

```
(setq org-startup-with-inline-images t)
```

2. Set inline config (see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621495/emacs-org-display-inline-images#comment85508568_32111919)):

```
(setq org-display-inline-images t) 
(setq org-redisplay-inline-images t) 
(setq org-startup-with-inline-images "inlineimages")
```

None of the two above (or any combination of) work. When I open the file, I always see the text `[[my-image.png]]` instead of the image. Using `C-c C-x C-v` works but I need to do it every time.

I have actually another related problem which is I can't set `visual-line-mode` by default at startup either. Maybe I have an issue with my org-mode settings? I can't figure out what is causing these issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2) is wrong: there is a function `org-display-inline-images` but no variable of that name. Similarly there is a function `org-redisplay-inline-images` but again no variable of that name.

If you look at the doc string of `org-display-inline-images`, you will find the conditions that the link has to obey in order to be considered as an inline image:

```
An inline image is a link which follows either of these
conventions:

  1. Its path is a file with an extension matching return value
     from `image-file-name-regexp' and it has no contents.

  2. Its description consists in a single link of the previous
     type.  In this case, that link must be a well-formed plain
     or angle link, i.e., it must have an explicit \"file\" type.
```

I will be the first to admit that this description is *NOT* a model of clarity. However, it does point out the fact that there *are* restrictions. The last sentence in particular is telling: `it must have an explicit "file" type`.

A little experimentation shows that the following works (assuming there is a file `foo.jpg` containing the image in the same directory as the Org file):

```
#+STARTUP: inlineimages showall

* Inline images?

   [[file:foo.jpg]]
```

If you want to set it permanently, then add

```
(setq org-startup-with-inline-images t)
```

to your init file.

Comment: Thanks, I did try `(setq org-startup-with-inline-images t)` in my init file and that doesn't work. `#+STARTUP: inlineimages showall` works for the file where I put it in but ideally I would like that to be set globally somehow.

Comment: Maybe something in your init file curdles things: try with `emacs -q`, then evaluate `(setq org-startup-with-inline-images t)` then open the Org mode file. That should work. If it does, then something is wrong with your init file.

Comment: Thanks! Found the culprit: Setting `(setq org-agenda-files '("~/org"))` breaks `(setq org-startup-with-inline-images t)`. Any idea why? If I remove the line setting the `org-agenda-files` then the inline images load by default.

Comment: I can also call `(setq org-startup-with-inline-images t)` before I call `(setq org-agenda-files '("~/org"))` and that works too. Weird.

Comment: That does not sound right at all: can you reproduce that behavior from `emacs -q`?